# How to run Slenium+Java+Cucumber without ide

Tags: java, selenium, ide, cucumber

Hello there are tests written on Java + cucumber
The structure is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fip8y.png

The main question is how to run this tests not from the IDE, say from the console or even wrap it all in jar file

The problems encountered are that you need the main class to create a jar,

It seems as there is a certain java cucumber.api.cli.Main - but how to use it I do not understand. Either way, there's probably a way to run this just from the command line. Please tell us how to do it?

Comment: Read this tutorial https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/run-cucumber-test-from-command-line-terminal/

Comment: I would run my tests through maven. Then you can run it with the console or any CI tool like Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Maven with following terminal script :

```
$brew install maven
```

After brew installation, you need to go to the project directory which includes pom.xml file in terminal :

```
$cd /path/of/your/project
```

And finally you can run following command to run your tests :

```
$mvn clean test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below on command prompt.

java -cp "E:\Workspace\CucumberProj\Jars*;E:\Workspace\CucumberProj\bin" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue stepDefination E:\Workspace\CucumberProj\Feature\Login_Test.feature